# How to play YouTube video using object tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, video, youtube

I am trying to play YouTube video by object tag in HTML:

```
<object id="video" width="100%" height="360" data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ 'excursion_'+id+'.youtube' | translate }}"></object>
```

I can't find the event to play them.

By the way, I can not use the iframe tag.

I try this:

```
$('.overlay').on('click', function(){

        $(this).css('display','none');
        $(".ytp-large-play-button ytp-button").click();
        console.log("play video");

});
```

And this:

```
$('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {

    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();

});
```